# Generalization of Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

For the inverse function theorem in one dimension, we require that the point we are testing (call it x), must be such that f'(x) is not equal to 0. This makes sense as if f is continously differentiable, this would imply f(x) would be strictly increasing or decreasing around x. In the multivariable dimension we replace the requirement that f'(x) not equal to 0 to be that Df(x) is invertible. Why do we do this? (what intuitive reason can we give for this?)

Comment: I'm not sure there is a simple characterisation as with monotonicity in the single variable case.

Comment: The derivative is a "local linear approximation" to the function. So if the derivative is invertible (meaning $f'(x) \neq 0$ in dimension 1, and $Df$ nonsingular in higher dimensions), it means that the local linear approximation is invertible, and so intuitively the function should be invertible near the point, since the derivative is a "good" approximation.